# Remove Products From Category

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to remove all products from a specific category. I thought a solution but I'm not sure that its the best way? It loops all products and remove the specified product_cat term.

Another solution thought was deleting category. I digged into woocommerce files.. `wp_delete_term($id, "product_cat")` is deletes category and removes the category term from products. This could be awesome if it wasn't delete category taxonomy :)

Is there a way to do this? Something like this `wp_remove_object_terms($product_id, $category_id, 'product_cat');` . Just I don't want this action for a specific product.. I want to remove this category from all products.

Comment: If you’re removing _all_ products can’t you just delete the term?

Comment: This is my first time developing a wordpress plugin.. How can i do this?

Comment: ? You included it in the question: wp_delete_term

Comment: @JacobPeattie doesn't it remove the category, too? Let's try id :)

Comment: I don’t understand. The term is the category.